# How to implement REST API with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-universal

When angular bundle the server files throw me warnings
"Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kerberos'" and other modules from mongodb.
That happen when i install mongoose and try to connect with a db.
The application work, but i don't know how to get rid of this errors.

Tried to import "mongoose" like that "const mongoose = require("mongoose")" but the warnings are still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Angular is a **Frontend Framework**. What does **Angular Universal** do? It render the first instance of your app on server side.
This means not you can handle backend code like mongoose and so on. This part sit on you backend (like `NodeJS`, `PHP` and so on).

Short: Mongoose is not for frontend and you should never use it inside frontend! (Security risk)

Comment: And where are the logic...? What im see is that, Angular create for me server.ts what is the absolutely normal Express server. And if im not wrong i can do whatever what i want with that. I understand this is for backend.

Comment: If you wanna do it really look here: https://www.positronx.io/build-angular-universal-crud-app-with-mongodb-server-side-rendering/ A GitHub example is available, too

Comment: Thank you Flo! I will look that. But what is your advice for a real project? To to like that or do it convention way?

Comment: Yes, its possible to use Universal for a backend, too. But I would use all backend stuff in a separate project. It's not sooo wrong to do it in your opinion, but I split this two parts.

Comment: I Read the post what u give me, and run the repo in the post on my machina. Actually its the same like min, again throw warnings about mognodb and mognoose. I think this is normal.
P.S. U are right if i merge the backend and frontend in one moment that can become really messy.